# Pleasure and reward

Tags: emotion, motivation

What exactly is pleasure? 
Is pleasure in some sense 'thoughts'? If you are given opiates, you will feel some sort of pleasure, even if you don't think about anything, but perhaps you are having some sort of more primitive 'thoughts' that can't be detected. 
Is pleasure just some sort of indicator of your neurotransmitters? Just as you might feel hot/cold, you might feel pleasure/pain. If it's not this way, and instead perhaps the previous (pleasure are some type of thoughts), then perhaps favorable levels of neurotrasmitters make pleasurable thoughts more likely to occur, explaining the correlation with neurotransmitters and various feelings.

By what way does a person decide to be pragmatic, in something like the marshmallow test? Is there some sort of pleasure that occurs, if you follow a pragmatic decision? 
Or could it be that we naturally have a strong tendency to have almost obsessive thoughts of the future, and being rational about it? Meaning, we might not even get any sort of pleasure from being pragmatic - it's just something that we do, because we get repetitive thoughts of "that's reasonable" ?

Comment: This question is probably far too broad as it stands.  It might be better to focus on just one of the areas mentioned - the biological basis of pleasure, or the relationship between thoughts and emotions, or the role of pleasure in learning...